# Problem with text becoming equation

Tags: math-mode

Somehow the text between the formulas also have the formula "style". I want it to look like the text above the first formula (normal

The second picture is of the code as it's stand right now. If i remove the second $ in the end of the first formula and place it before the last frac of the first formula the text works, but the formula doesn't

[image: input]

EDIT:
I tried the first fix, and the text came out alright, but the formual had errors. 
The code:

```
\[\Delta \mu = ((\[\frac{\partial \mu}{\partial \theta}\]\ \Delta \theta)^2+(\[\frac{\partial \mu}{\partial a}\]\ \Delta a)^2)^\[\frac{1}{2}\]\ \]    Regner så usikkerheten med hensyn på  for konstant fart ved hjelp av formelen
```

(for the top formula, the last one works just fine. )
This is the new formula.
[image: New formula]

Comment: you have `\[` inside `$ ... $`  remove all the `$` and the `\newline`  and just have a single `\[..\]` around each display. Please always post code not just an image of code

Comment: In your edit you have `\[\Delta \mu = ((\[`  that is starting a display math inside display math, which doesn't work (and can't mean anything) just remove the inner `\[` Also, I edited the question for language.

Answer (score 1):

You want something like:
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}


zzzz $\mu_2$ zzz formua:
\[\Delta \mu = ((\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}  \ldots\]
for konstant zzzformual:
\[\Delta\theta=\ldots\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, have class but I'll try it later.